# Wordpress plugins fail over sftp (WinSCP)

Tags: wordpress

We have clients that are using SFTP (WinSCP) to install wp plugins and are getting file permissions errors. 
On Centos7 VM we set permissions to default Files 0644 and Folders 0755 with user:apache 
When we set permissions to 777 on public and disable SE-linux the plugins seem to install successfully with no problem. We do not want to keep changing files to 777 as this is a security risk.

This is the error below:

> The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some
>   files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.:
>   wp-comments-post.php, wp-activate.php, wp-includes/script-loader.php,
>   wp-includes/theme.php, wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php,
>   wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-post-types-controller.php,
>   wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-users-controller.php,
>   wp-includes/default-filters.php, wp-includes/comment.php,
>   wp-includes/version.php, wp-includes/js/wp-api.min.js,
>   wp-includes/js/media-views.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.js.gz,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/utils/validate.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/plugin.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/plugin.min.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.min.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.min.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/tabfocus/plugin.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/tabfocus/plugin.min.js,
>   wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/colorpicker/plugin.js Installation
>   Failed

Is there an alternative to work around this?

Comment: Hi guys also just to add :

Comment: this is when we try to update in wp :                                                                  Connection Information
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

Hostname 
example: www.wordpress.org
FTP Username 
FTP Password 
This password will not be stored on the server.
Connection Type
 FTP
 FTPS (SSL)
Cancel